# Unable to use FindFirstCHangeNotification and FindNextChangeNotification for notification of directory changes

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

I am trying to use FindFirstChangeNotification and FindNextChangeNotification for getting directory change notifications. The code below which I am running as a service(As Administrator) and debugging in the visual studio 2017 debugger (also as administrator)  is not triggering any change notifications. Your suggestions are appreciated.

Code is as below;

```
    HANDLE *handlestowatch;
    vector<string> allwatcheddirs={"dir1","dir2"};
    void InitHandlesToWatch()
    {
    HANDLE hchng;
    handlestowatch = new HANDLE[allwatcheddirs.size()];
     for (int i = 0; i < allwatcheddirs.size(); i++)
       {
       hchng = FindFirstChangeNotificationA(allwatcheddirs[i].c_str(), TRUE,  FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_WRITE);
    handlestowatch[i] = hchng;
       }

   }

  void ContinueHandlesWatch()
  {

   for (int i = 0; i < allwatcheddirs.size(); i++)
     {
     FindNextChangeNotification(handlestowatch[i]);
   }
  GetChangedDirs();

  }


  void CloseHandlesToWatch()
 {
    for (int i = 0; i < allwatcheddirs.size(); i++)
   {
        FindCloseChangeNotification(handlestowatch[i]);
   }

 }

  void GetChangedDirs()
  {
  vector<string>::iterator it;
  int ret;
  for (int i = 0; i < allwatcheddirs.size(); i++)
  {
    ret=WaitForSingleObject(handlestowatch[i], 100);
    if (ret == WAIT_OBJECT_0)
    {
    AddEntryLog(string("change in directory :")+allwathcheddirs[i]);
    }

  }
}

 bool NotStopped=true;

 void main()
 {
  InitHandlesToWatch();
  while(NotStopped)
  {
  ContinueHandlesToWatch)
  }
 CloseHandlesToWatch();
 }
```

Comment: why you use this api instead *ReadDirectoryChangesW* ?

Comment: There's no error handling anywhere. If things don't work, the first order of action should be finding out why. The documentation will tell you how errors are reported. It's mandatory reading for *any* API call you make.

Comment: Also, looping over your `HANDLE` array and calling `WaitForSingleObject` on each entry is wrong, no matter what. There's [MsgWaitForMultipleObjects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-msgwaitformultipleobjects) that provides a robust solution, which doesn't waste CPU resources like your polling approach.

Comment: @ RbMm I only need to know if directory is changed. Not what actually changed in the directory. @IInspectable I am never getting the WAIT_OBJECT_0 return value. I will check up on the return values of whether FindFirstChangeNotification is INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE.I am also interested to know if my usage of the API is right.

Comment: There is a problem with WaitForMultipleObjects in that I can't get all the HANDLES changed. It only returns one value which is the first change in the HANDLES.

Comment: I am checking up on return values and will get back.

Comment: FindFIrst and FindNext are returning success.There are no errors.

Comment: Sorry, meant [WaitForMultipleObjects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-waitformultipleobjects). There's no problem here. If you pass `FALSE` for `bWaitAll`, it will indeed only return the index of a single object. However, it doesn't change the state of any other objects, so you can just call `WaitForMultipleObjects` again, and get the next one.

Comment: I am trying with WaitForMultipleObjects in a loop

Comment: I am getting only WAIT_TIMEOUT. I change a file in the monitored directory, but there is no change notification for that directory.

Comment: [mcve] required then. Though you would probably use a timeout of `INFINITE`, and thus never observe a return value of `WAIT_TIMEOUT`.

Comment: even if you not need what actually changed in the directory much more better direct call *ReadDirectoryChangesW*. and not need dedicated thread which wait. use *BindIoCompletionCallback* on directory handle

Comment: Using a higher timeout seems to work. Will get back with final results

Comment: Using a higher timeout of 30 seconds worked. But it fires repeatedly unless it is closed with FindCloseChangeNotification

Answer (score 0):

According to the [`FindNextChangeNotification`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-findnextchangenotification#remarks):

> Each successful call to FindNextChangeNotification must be followed by
> a call to one of the wait functions. If the wait function returns for
> any reason other than the change notification handle being signaled
> (for example, if the wait times out), the application must retry the
> wait. Failing to follow this rule can cause the system to eventually
> run out of resources. It can also cause the application to miss some
> change notifications.

You can refer to [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/obtaining-directory-change-notifications) on msdn

Comment: If I make a change when the service is not in a waiting state, but in some other processing. will change be detected afterward in the wait?. what is the workaround in this case.

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue you mentioned with the example on msdn. I added a delay before wait and made changes during it. After the delay ends, the changes can be detected.